# stride(from: 0.0, to: 10.0, by: 2.0) using Float type instead of Double?

Tags: swift, sequence, list-comprehension, stride

When generating a sequence with `stride`, how do I pass type hint to Swift to use `Float` instead of `Double`?

```
let floats = Array(stride(from: -160.0, to: 0.0, by: 1.0)) // how to use Float instead of Double?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let floats = Array(stride(from: Float(-160.0), to: Float(0.0), by: Float(1.0)))
print(type(of: floats.first!))
```

improved by comments:

```
let floats = Array(stride(from: Float(-160.0), to:0.0, by: 1.0))
print(type(of: floats.first!))
```

this is possible too

```
let strideTo: StrideTo<Float> = stride(from: -160.0, to: 0.0, by: 1.0)
let floats = Array(strideTo)

print(type(of: floats.first!))
```

Improved by Sulthan

```
let floats = Array(stride(from: -160.0 as Float, to: 0.0, by: 1.0))
print(type(of: floats.first!))
```

Array Generic syntax allows this:

```
let floats = Array<Float>(stride(from: -160.0, to: 0.0, by: 1.0))
print(type(of: floats.first!))
```

Comment: Is there not a cleaner way to do this than to repeat the type signature?

Comment: Its enough to do it once actually

Comment: Also, writing `0 as Float` is probably cleaner than invoking initializers.

Comment: @Sulthan what is the implementation difference between `Float(0)` and `0 as Float`?

Comment: @PetrusTheron `0 as Float` is a literal of type `Float`. `Float(0)` is a literal of type `Double` wrapped in `Float.init` call.